# subsetting by a variable name of a column r

Tags: r

```
    row.names   Hospital                          State Heart Attack    Heart Failure
1   2275    PROVIDENCE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL            TX  16.1             9.1                 
2   2276    MEMORIAL HERMANN BAPTIST ORANGE HOSPITALTX  16.3            14.3       
4   2278    UNITED REGIONAL HEALTH CARE SYSTEM      TX  17.4            15.1    
5   2279    ST JOSEPH REGIONAL HEALTH CENTER        TX  15.7            15.6
6   2280    PARKLAND HEALTH AND HOSPITAL SYSTEM     TX  12.9            11.2    
7   2281    UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS MEDICAL BRANCH GAL  TX  17.4            11.8
```

Hello R peeps, 
 I need to get a row.name where input, which is variable column name (Heart Attack or Heart Failure) is minimum for that column.
 
  In the exmple above, if I input "Heart failure" it needs to return 
[1] 2275
Which row name in the first row.
 so far I got this:
inds<-subset(wfperstate, wfperstate[[outname]]==min)
where wfperstate is my data frame
outname is my input
Please, help!

Comment: You should study more of the introductory texts available at CRAN.

Comment: `subset` is not recommended (at best, hard to use) for such a "non-interactive" mode, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 1):

To transform my last comment into a function :

```
get_min_rowname <- 
   function(dat,col)
     dat[which.min(dat[[col]]),"row.names"]
```

Then you apply it :

```
get_min_rowname(wfperstate, "Heart Attack")
get_min_rowname(wfperstate, "Heart Failure")
```